# How to remove credit card

Tags: store

My brother bought a Microsoft Lumia 435 and wanted to buy an app. Since he is too young for his own credit card, we used mine. Now he had this app, but I want to make sure, that he will not buy anything with my credit card. When I open any app on his phone, there is my card and I see no option to remove it. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, need to go to https://commerce.microsoft.com/PaymentHub/, there is payment history and under account it is possible to remove card.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a payment option from your Microsoft account follow these steps:

1. Go to https://account.microsoft.com/ and login with your MS account.
2. Navigate to *Payment & Billing -> Payment Options*.
3. Remove the payment method from here.